# Openvz vs OpenVZ within SolusVM

Tags: virtualization, vps, openvz, solusvm

is there a difference from a VPS user point of view between regular OpenVZ and OpenVZ from within SolusVM ?

My understanding was that OpenVZ doesn't have the overhead of a true hypervisor and then it is faster and more efficient, but with SolusVM you have a true hypervisor so do one loose the efficiency advantage over regular OpenVZ ?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want short answer, **No, you don't loose anything**. This soulution like Virtuozzo 7, when hypervisor could run OpenVZ containers and KVM or XEN virtual machines, because in some cases you couldn't do some things in OpenVZ containers(some sysctl tuning or use some iptables modules, for example).

Answer (score 0):

No, you wont. OpenVZ is actually a jailed shell, a container which mainly depend only on the Kernel of the underlying OS/Hypervisor. Irrespective of the solution you are using like Virtuozzo or ProxmoxVE (I guess they have switched to LXC now). OpenVZ should perform efficiently.